# Que me falta en este algoritmo para que me imprima la suma de solo los números pares y positivos del vector?

Tags: java

Como hago para que me imprima la suma de los números del vector con las condiciones que le puse en el if ya que me está imprimiendo la suma de todos lo cual es incorrecto.

```
package sumapares;

public class SumaPares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int suma = 0;
        int vectorEntrada[] = {0, 2, 1, 65, 66, 78, 12, 11, 90, 13, -8};
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorEntrada.length; i++) {
        if ((vectorEntrada[i] % 2 == 0) && (vectorEntrada[i] > 0));
        suma += vectorEntrada[i];
        }

        System.out.println(suma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Al finalizar la linea del if tienes un punto y coma (;). corrígelo. También te recomiendo al igual que a todos los usuarios nuevos que leas [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas y también hagas un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. te ayudara mucho en el futuro.

Comment: Si deseas obtener simplemente el resultado final en lugar de los resultados parciales de la suma, saca System.out.println(suma); del for.

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa es casi correcto pero debes iterar los valores en la matriz y verificar la condiciòn, te sugiero siempre indentar tu còdigo para que entiendas como es el flujo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int suma = 0;
    int vectorEntrada[] = {0, 2, 1, 65, 66, 78, 12, 11, 90, 13, -8};
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorEntrada.length; i++) {
         if ((vectorEntrada[i] % 2 == 0) && (vectorEntrada[i] > 0)){ //Verifica condicion
             suma += vectorEntrada[i];
         }
    }
    System.out.println(suma);
  }
```